# Find $\,\,e^{-1/4}\,$ to within $0.0002$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am using Taylor's Inequality to solve this problem but this formula [(page 607)](http://books.google.com/books?id=uYxE7bzhh08C&pg=PA608&lpg=PA608&dq=taylor%27s+inequality+formula+stewart&source=bl&ots=PYmGHkGEfE&sig=rJt5OorULP5t375sjkXF9vXWx-A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c_gYUumFG8qoigLxwoHYDg&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=taylor%27s%20inequality%20formula%20stewart&f=false) is getting on my nerves and the textbook does not do a good job of explaining how to do this problem and I've gone to khanacademy and patrickjmt and they do not help me.

But I will try to interpret the problem anyways.  I know that M is the max value for the nth term I want but added to another.  The remainder must be less than or equal to $.0002$, so $R_n(x) \leq .0002$.  I'm guessing that the max value of M is $1$ but I'm not sure.  I do not know how to solve for what n is then.  I do know the Taylor series expansion for $e^x$ though but I do not know what term I should stop at.  Please help?  I'm extremely frustrated.

Comment: Well, $e^{-\frac{1}{4}}=0.77880078307140486824517026697832064730$.

Comment: I was hoping to use Taylor's inequality to find the answer.

Comment: For $x = -\frac14$, the exponential series $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ is an alternating series and the absolute value of the terms decreases strictly. So the error is at most the first omitted term.

Comment: @Dietrich: $e^{-\frac14}$ is irrational, isn't it?

Answer (score 12):

We have 
$$ e^{-1/4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{4^nn!}.$$
This is an alternating series with summands decreasing in absolute value. Therefore, the error will we less than the first summand you drop. That is, if you compute the approximation
$$ e^{-1/4}\approx \sum_{n=0}^N\frac{(-1)^n}{4^nn!},$$
then the error will be $<\frac{1}{4^{N+1}(N+1)!}$. Note that already $N=3$ leads to $\frac{1}{4^{N+1}(N+1)!}\approx 0.00016$. Therefore the approximation
$$ e^{-1/4}\approx 1-\frac1{4}+\frac1{16\cdot 2}-\frac1{64\cdot 6}=\frac{299}{384}$$
is good enough for your purpose.

Answer (score 5):

It is easiest if we take advantage of the fact that the series for $e^{-1/4}$ is an **Alternating Series**. But instead we will use the harder to work with, and generally less useful, inequality of the text.

Suppose that the *last* term we use in the approximation is $\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$, where $x=-\dfrac{1}{4}$.

Then the *error* we make is $\dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(z)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$, where all we know about $z$ is that it is between $-\frac{1}{4}$ and $0$.

Now any derivative of $e^t$, including the $(n+1)$-th, is $e^t$. So we want to estimate $e^z$. Since $z$ is between $-\frac{1}{4}$ and $0$, we can say for sure that $e^{-1/4}\lt e^z\lt e^0=1$.

Thus for sure our error has absolute value less than $\dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{n+1}$.

Make this less than $0.0002$. Because of the $(n+1)!$, the inequality is unpleasant to attack algebraically. So we just fool around. Try $n=3$. It works! Try to be cheaper, using $n=2$: the inequality is not satisfied, so $n=2$ may not be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

First note that the series is $$e^x=1+x+\frac {x^2}{2!}+\frac {x^3}{3!}+\dots$$

When $x$ is negative the series is a convergent alternating series and [once the terms are decreasing in magnitude] the error is at most the magnitude of the last term you use (also of the first term you don't use).

$0.0002=\frac 1{5000}$

Note that the term in $x^3$ has denominator $64\times 6$ which is a little under 400. The term in $x^4$ has denominator a bit under $16 \times 400 =6400 \gt 5000$

So you can safely terminate at the $x^3$ term.